# How to submit pull request from cloned repo by composer?

Tags: php, git, github, yii2, composer-php

I am working with Yii2 which uses [Composer](http://composer.org). Composer clones a lot of repos (mostly from [Github](http://github.com)) in the `vendor` folder as defined in `composer.json`.

Working with such a repo I sometimes find bugs or need to improve/enhance the code in the repo. Since I use this repo in my project for a longer time I want to get my code into the original repo.

- How can I help the repo owner and submit a pull request to integrate my code optimizations?
- Do I have to fork his repo first?
- What `git` commands do I have to use?
- How to update the repo without breaking the `composer update` feature in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do you a composer install use

```
 --prefer-source
```

This keeps the git directory. You will need a forked version on git hub to submit the source code changes. Add this with the command

```
git remote add someName (repo URL)
```

Where some name can be anything. Run this when you have cd ed to the directory you want to change

Then commit and push with

```
git push someName branchname
```

When you change the source in the vendor folder your next composer update will detect changes and ask you what to do.